# Using QWebEngineView seems to disrupt QPropertyAnimation smoothness, even if QWebEngineView has just been destroyed

Tags: c++, qt, qwebengineview, qpropertyanimation

I have a problem with QPropertyAnimation when QWebEngineView is used in the same QMainWindow.

If I create 15 QPropertyAnimation (animate QGraphicsRectItem),
and in the same time I use a QWebEngineView, then animations become very slow.

I have created a demo (to compile yourself), with minimum usefull source code : https://media.nperf.com/files/misc/src_sandbox_web_animation.zip

[image]

**Tests made with one QMainWindow :**

After creating QWebEngineView, if I *kill it*, *the problem continues*.

If I use *QTimer loop* instead of QPropertyAnimation, *the problem is the same*.

**Tests made with two QMainWindow :**

If I embed the QWebEngineView in an *external window* (new QMainWindow), then *animations become smooth again*.
This new QMainWindow is not the same QMainWindow where QPropertyAnimations are running.

However, this is not an acceptable solution for me, but this shows that there is a resource that is shared between QWebEngineView and QPropertyAnimations,
if and only if the QWebEngineView was created in the same QMainWindow.

**So I wonder :**

- Did I kill the QWebEngineView correctly ?
- Is there a way to seperate QWebEngineView threads from QMainWindow ?
- Or any other solution...

**Environment context :**

This problem exist with two environments, win10/Qt5.15.2 and Mac/Qt5.15.0.

But does not exist with ubuntu20/Qt5.12 and ubuntu18/Qt5.9.2.

**Reproductible code example (Code description of demo shared):**

1. The QPropertyAnimation change size of a QGraphicsRectItem :

```
class AnimationBarItem : public QObject, public QGraphicsRectItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QRectF rect READ rect WRITE setRect)
    ...
}
class AnimationBar : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...
    AnimationBarItem *bar = nullptr;
}
    
void AnimationBar::setPourcent(qreal pourc){
  QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(bar, "rect");
  animation->setDuration(200);
  animation->setStartValue(QRect(0, 0, 0, mH));
  animation->setEndValue(QRect(0, 0, ww,mH));
  animation->start();    
}
```

2. The QWebEngineView is created as follow :

```
mWebEngineView = new QWebEngineView();//can't link to this, for compatibility with my project
mWebEnginePage = new QWebEnginePage(mWebEngineView);
mWebEnginePage->setView(mWebEngineView);
mWebEngineView->setUrl(QUrl("http://www.google.com"));
```

3. then add in QMainWindow with method :

```
mLayoutForBrowse=new QVBoxLayout(ui->ZONE_webview);
mLayoutForBrowse->addWidget(mWebEngineView);
```

4. Or, in a new QMainWindow :

   And not in the same QMainWindow like previous point, with :

```
this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

5. killing webview :

```
void MainWindow::killWebView(bool is){
    if (mWebEngineView!=nullptr) mWebEngineView->stop();
    mWebEngineView->deleteLater();
    mLayoutForBrowse->deleteLater();
    mWebEnginePage->deleteLater();
    mWebEngineView=nullptr;
    mLayoutForBrowse=nullptr;
    mWebEnginePage=nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add some [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: please provide a [mre] (not external links), also read [ask] and review the [tour]